# Bazel `cmake` cannot download repo itself but manually retrying outside works?

Tags: cmake, bazel

I am trying to build [a repo](https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime-extensions/tree/main) that is a CMake project, but I use Bazel. To do this, I use [`rules_foreign_cc`](https://bazelbuild.github.io/rules_foreign_cc/0.9.0/rules.html) and specify the BUILD file for the repo as follows:

```
load("@rules_foreign_cc//foreign_cc:defs.bzl", "cmake")

filegroup(
    name = "all_srcs",
    srcs = glob(["**"]),
)

cc_library(
    name = "include",
    hdrs = glob(["includes/**"]),
    strip_include_prefix = "includes",
)


cmake(
    name = "onnx_extensions",
    lib_source = ":all_srcs",
    cache_entries = {
        "OCOS_ONNXRUNTIME_VERSION": "1.16.2",
    },
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

However, I get the following error when trying to build a binary that depends on this repo:

```
+ /private/var/tmp/_bazel_victor/1cabe6594cc48c856544c639052f58cd/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/32/execroot/morris/external/cmake-3.26.4-macos-universal/bin/cmake 
-DOCOS_ONNXRUNTIME_VERSION=1.16.2 
-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/private/var/tmp/_bazel_victor/1cabe6594cc48c856544c639052f58cd/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/32/execroot/morris/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/external/onnx_runtime_extensions/onnx_extensions.build_tmpdir/crosstool_bazel.cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release 
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/private/var/tmp/_bazel_victor/1cabe6594cc48c856544c639052f58cd/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/32/execroot/morris/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/external/onnx_runtime_extensions/onnx_extensions '
-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/private/var/tmp/_bazel_victor/1cabe6594cc48c856544c639052f58cd/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/32/execroot/morris/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/external/onnx_runtime_extensions/onnx_extensions.ext_build_deps;external/onnx_runtime/include;bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/external/onnx_runtime/include' 
-DCMAKE_RANLIB= -G 'Unix Makefiles'
/private/var/tmp/_bazel_victor/1cabe6594cc48c856544c639052f58cd/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/32/execroot/morris/external/onnx_runtime_extensions
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 15.0.0.15000038
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 15.0.0.15000038
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_victor/1cabe6594cc48c856544c639052f58cd/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/32/execroot/morris/external/local_config_cc/cc_wrapper.sh - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_victor/1cabe6594cc48c856544c639052f58cd/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/32/execroot/morris/external/local_config_cc/cc_wrapper.sh - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR=x86_64
-- CMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM=
-- ONNX Runtime URL: https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime/releases/download/v1.16.2/onnxruntime-osx-universal2-1.16.2.tgz
[ 11%] Creating directories for 'onnxruntime-populate'
[ 22%] Performing download step (download, verify and extract) for 'onnxruntime-populate'
-- Downloading...
   dst='/private/var/tmp/_bazel_victor/1cabe6594cc48c856544c639052f58cd/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/32/execroot/morris/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/external/onnx_runtime_extensions/onnx_extensions.build_tmpdir/_deps/onnxruntime-subbuild/onnxruntime-populate-prefix/src/onnxruntime-osx-universal2-1.16.2.tgz'
   timeout='none'
   inactivity timeout='none'
-- Using src='https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime/releases/download/v1.16.2/onnxruntime-osx-universal2-1.16.2.tgz'
-- Retrying...
-- Using src='https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime/releases/download/v1.16.2/onnxruntime-osx-universal2-1.16.2.tgz'
-- Retry after 5 seconds (attempt #2) ...
-- Using src='https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime/releases/download/v1.16.2/onnxruntime-osx-universal2-1.16.2.tgz'
-- Retry after 5 seconds (attempt #3) ...
-- Using src='https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime/releases/download/v1.16.2/onnxruntime-osx-universal2-1.16.2.tgz'
-- Retry after 15 seconds (attempt #4) ...
-- Using src='https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime/releases/download/v1.16.2/onnxruntime-osx-universal2-1.16.2.tgz'
-- Retry after 60 seconds (attempt #5) ...
-- Using src='https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime/releases/download/v1.16.2/onnxruntime-osx-universal2-1.16.2.tgz'
CMake Error at onnxruntime-subbuild/onnxruntime-populate-prefix/src/onnxruntime-populate-stamp/download-onnxruntime-populate.cmake:170 (message):
  Each download failed!

    error: downloading 'https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime/releases/download/v1.16.2/onnxruntime-osx-universal2-1.16.2.tgz' failed
          status_code: 7
          status_string: "Couldn't connect to server"
          log:
          --- LOG BEGIN ---
            Trying 140.82.112.4:443...

  Immediate connect fail for 140.82.112.4: Operation not permitted

  Closing connection 0
```

For whatever reason, CMake doesn't seem to be able to download a repo. Tracing through the CMake code led me to this section as the logic for the download:

```
file(
        DOWNLOAD
        "${url}" "/private/var/tmp/_bazel_victor/1cabe6594cc48c856544c639052f58cd/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/5/execroot/morris/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/external/onnx_runtime_extensions/onnx_extensions.build_tmpdir/_deps/onnxruntime-subbuild/onnxruntime-populate-prefix/src/onnxruntime-osx-universal2-1.16.2.tgz"
        SHOW_PROGRESS
        # no TIMEOUT
        # no INACTIVITY_TIMEOUT
        STATUS status
        LOG log
        
        
        )
```

which doesn't seem to have any obvious issues.

Furthermore, I copied the actual CMake command in the log and **ran it myself** in a separate directory:

```
/private/var/tmp/_bazel_victor/1cabe6594cc48c856544c639052f58cd/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/32/execroot/morris/external/cmake-3.26.4-macos-universal/bin/cmake 
-DOCOS_ONNXRUNTIME_VERSION=1.16.2 
-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/private/var/tmp/_bazel_victor/1cabe6594cc48c856544c639052f58cd/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/32/execroot/morris/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/external/onnx_runtime_extensions/onnx_extensions.build_tmpdir/crosstool_bazel.cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release 
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/private/var/tmp/_bazel_victor/1cabe6594cc48c856544c639052f58cd/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/32/execroot/morris/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/external/onnx_runtime_extensions/onnx_extensions '
-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/private/var/tmp/_bazel_victor/1cabe6594cc48c856544c639052f58cd/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/32/execroot/morris/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/external/onnx_runtime_extensions/onnx_extensions.ext_build_deps;external/onnx_runtime/include;bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/external/onnx_runtime/include' 
-DCMAKE_RANLIB= -G 'Unix Makefiles'
/private/var/tmp/_bazel_victor/1cabe6594cc48c856544c639052f58cd/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/32/execroot/morris/external/onnx_runtime_extensions
```

and **this runs without any issues**. So it only seems to fail when Bazel tries to run this, for some reason.

Could any Bazel experts let me know what might be going on? I am currently running this on MacOS 13.5, and have `rules_foreign_cc_dependencies` set up for `3.26.4`:

```
load("@rules_foreign_cc//foreign_cc:repositories.bzl", "rules_foreign_cc_dependencies")
rules_foreign_cc_dependencies(cmake_version = "3.26.4")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just ran into the same problem. including `tags = ["requires-network"]` to the build file resolved the issue. You should do something like:

```
cmake(
    name = "onnx_extensions",
    lib_source = ":all_srcs",
    tags = ["requires-network"],
    cache_entries = {
        "OCOS_ONNXRUNTIME_VERSION": "1.16.2",
    },
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```